# MVC JavaScript code does not work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do the mail box. Codes I want to hide my mail I get mail all the details of the show and yet does not work.

Show/Hidden class id='Detay'

Nuget Package = MimeKit

Show part

Clicked javascript I want to hide the data-side was the same.

```
 <span onclick="Goster()" class="sender" data-id="@item.MessageId" title="@item.From">@item.From </span>
```

It was to hideShow/hidden

```
   <div id="Detay" data-id="@item.MessageId" style="display: none">
```

hidden button

```
<div class="messagebar-item-left">
                                                                            <a onclick="Gizle()" href="#" class="btn-back-message-list">
                                                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left bigger-110 middle blue"></i>
                                                                                <b onclick="Gizle" class="middle bigger-110">Geri</b>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
```

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Gizle() {
        var divObject = document.getElementById('Detay');
        divObject.style.display = 'none';
    }
    function Goster() {
        var divObject = document.getElementById('Detay');
        divObject.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each html element must have a unique id,
in your code you are assigning the same id to multiple div elements inside a foreach loop! you have to make it unique by adding a number for example;

```
<!--Show / Hidden to be part-->
<div id="Detay@(item.MessageId)" style="display: none">
```

when you will call show/hide you can parse the id like below:

```
<span onclick="Goster('Detay@(item.MessageId)')" class="sender" title="@item.From">@item.From </span>
```

and for hiding use this:

```
<b onclick="Gizle('Detay@(item.MessageId)')" class="bigger-110 middle">Geri</b>
```

finally you have to modify you javascript to accept the id parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Gizle(id) {
        $('#'+id).toggle(false);
    }

    function Goster(id) {
        $('#' + id).toggle(true);
   }
</script>
```

**[UPDATE]**
Full solution:

```
    <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-content-inner">
<div class="breadcrumbs ace-save-state" id="breadcrumbs">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-home home-icon">@Html.ActionLink("Ana Sayfa", "Index", "Home")</i>
</li>
<li class="active">Mail Kutusu</li>
</ul><!-- /.breadcrumb -->

</div>
<div class="page-content">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="tabbable">
<ul id="inbox-tabs" class="inbox-tabs nav nav-tabs padding-16 tab-size-bigger tab-space-1">
<li class="active">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#inbox" data-target="inbox">
<i class="blue ace-icon fa fa-inbox bigger-130"></i>
<span class="bigger-110">Gelen Kutusu</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#sent" data-target="sent">
<i class="orange ace-icon fa fa-location-arrow bigger-130"></i>
<span class="bigger-110">Sent</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content no-border no-padding">
<div id="inbox" class="tab-pane in active">
<div class="message-container">
<div class="message-navbar clearfix">
<div class="message-bar">
<div class="message-infobar" id="id-message-infobar">
<span class="blue bigger-150">Mesaj Kutusu</span>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="message-list-container">
<div class="message-list">
<!--<div class="message-item message-unread"> okunmamış-->
@foreach (var item in client.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date))
{
<div class="message-item">
<label class="inline">
<span class="lbl"></span>
</label>
<!--Show/Hidden Click-->
<span onclick="Goster('detay@(item.MessageId)')" class="sender" title="@item.From">@item.From </span>
<span class="time">@mvcHelper.saatAyarla(item.Date)</span>
@if (item.Attachments.Any())
{
<span class="attachment">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-paperclip"></i>
</span>
}
<span class="summary">
<span onclick="Goster('detay@(item.MessageId)')" class="text">
@item.Subject
</span>
</span>
</div>

<!--Show / Hidden to be part-->
<div id="detay@(item.MessageId)" style="display: none">
<div class="message-container">
<div id="id-message-list-navbar" class="message-navbar clearfix hide">
<div>

<div class="messagebar-item-right">
<div class="inline position-relative">
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
Sort &nbsp;
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down bigger-125"></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-lighter dropdown-menu-right dropdown-100">
<li>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check green"></i>
Date
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check invisible"></i>
From
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check invisible"></i>
Subject
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="id-message-item-navbar" class="message-navbar clearfix">
<div class="message-bar">

</div>
<div>
<div class="messagebar-item-left">
<a href="#" class="btn-back-message-list">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left blue bigger-110 middle"></i>
<b onclick="Gizle('detay@(item.MessageId)')" class="bigger-110 middle">Geri</b>
</a>
</div>
<div class="messagebar-item-right">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o bigger-110 orange"></i>
<span class="grey">@mvcHelper.saatAyarla(item.Date)</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="id-message-new-navbar" class="hide message-navbar clearfix">
<div>
<div class="messagebar-item-left">
<a onclick="Gizle()" href="#" class="btn-back-message-list">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left bigger-110 middle blue"></i>
<b onclick="Gizle" class="middle bigger-110">Geri</b>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="message-list-container">
<div class="message-list hide" id="message-list"></div>
<div class="message-content" id="id-message-content">
<div class="message-header clearfix">
<div class="pull-left">
<span class="blue bigger-125"> @item.Subject </span>
<div class="space-4"></div>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-star orange2"></i>
&nbsp;
<img class="middle" alt="John's Avatar" src="/Areas/admin/Content/images/avatars/avatar.png" width="32">
&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="sender">@item.From</a>
&nbsp;
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o bigger-110 orange middle"></i>
<span class="time grey">@mvcHelper.saatGoster(item.Date)</span>
</div>

</div>
<div class="hr hr-double"></div>
<div style="position: relative;" class="message-body ace-scroll">
<div style="display: block; height: 150px;" class="scroll-track scroll-visible scroll-active">
<div style="height: 127px; top: 0px;" class="scroll-bar"></div>
</div>
<div style="max-height: 150px;" class="scroll-content">
<p>

@item.GetTextBody(TextFormat.Plain)

</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hr hr-double"></div>

@if (item.Attachments.Any())
{
<div class="message-attachment clearfix">
<div class="attachment-title">
<span class="blue bolder bigger-110">Ekler</span>
&nbsp;
<span class="grey">@item.Attachments.Count()</span>
<div class="inline position-relative">
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
&nbsp;
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down bigger-125 middle"></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-lighter">
<li>
<a href="#">Download all as zip</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Display in slideshow</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<ul class="attachment-list pull-left list-unstyled">
@foreach (var attachment in item.Attachments)
{
<li>
<a href="#" class="attached-file">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-file-o bigger-110"></i>
<span class="attached-name">@mvcHelper.getAttachmentName(attachment.ToString())</span>
</a>
<span class="action-buttons">
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-download bigger-125 blue"></i>
</a>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-125 red"></i>
</a>
</span>
</li>

}
</ul>
</div>
}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

}



<!--ForEach End-->
</div>
</div>


<div class="message-footer clearfix">

<div class="pull-left"> Total</div>

<div class="pull-right">
<div class="inline middle"> page 1 of 16 </div>

&nbsp; &nbsp;
<ul class="pagination middle">
<li class="disabled">
<span>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-step-backward middle"></i>
</span>
</li>

<li class="disabled">
<span>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-left bigger-140 middle"></i>
</span>
</li>

<li>
<span>
<input value="1" maxlength="3" type="text">
</span>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-right bigger-140 middle"></i>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-step-forward middle"></i>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="hide message-footer message-footer-style2 clearfix">
<div class="pull-left"> </div>

<div class="pull-right">
<div class="inline middle"> </div>

&nbsp; &nbsp;
<ul class="pagination middle">
<li class="disabled">
<span>
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-150"></i>
</span>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-150"></i>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.tab-content -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Gizle(detayId) {
$('#'+detayId).toggle(false);
}
function Goster(detayId) {
$('#'+detayId).toggle(true); }

</script>
```

Comment: kindly inform me if you need Turkish explanation :)

Comment: sayfa içinde her id tek olmalı, foreach döngüsü içinde aynı id'yi birçok div elemanına veriyorsun (Detay), onun için id'leri farklılaştırmak için Detay'ın sonuna mesaj id'si ekleyebilirsin,

kodları yukarıda verdim nasıl olması gerektiğini, ayrıca goster/gizle fonksiyonunu çağırırken ilgili div id'sini yine kodlarda verdiğim gibi çağırman lazım.

kolay gelsin :)

Comment: teşekkürler farkına varıp değiştirdim kodları 'data-id' içerisine aldım onunla sadece ilk mesajı okuyabildim. sizin gönderdiğiniz kodları denedim lakin çalışmadı.

Comment: sizi uğraştırıyorum kusura bakmayın lakin hiçbir tepki vermiyor. :(

Comment: Don't worry :) jQuery eklemeyi unutma

Comment: Layout da referans olarak ekledim. messajeId string bir değer dönüyor ondan olabilir mi?

Comment: bu arada bootstrap collapse accordion'a bakmanı tavisye ederim:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp ve 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/

Comment: Teşekkürler kodlarınızı denedim ama bende bir sorun var belli sizin kodunuz gayet güzel çalışıyor benimki hala yerinde saymakta. jquery güncelledim lakin devam ediyor. eklediğiniz örnekler güzel onlar üzerinde çalışmalarıma devam ederim. Sorun devam ederse size ulaşmam için bir iletişim adresi verebilir misiniz.

Comment: acaba messajeId guid tipinde uzun bir string değer döndürüyor ondan olabilir mi?

Comment: rica ederim, Html5 için id benzersiz olmalı ve boşluk dışında herhangi karakter içerebilir, ama önceki versiyonlar öyle değil: http://xahlee.info/js/html_allowed_chars_in_attribute.html

Comment: jQuery dosyasını head kısmında yüklemeyi dene:


`<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>....</body></html>`

Comment: burada iletişim bilgileri paylaşılmaz sanırım, ama sorun devam ederse profilimden web siteme girip mesaj gönderebilirsin ;)

Comment: jquery layout ta var hocam. kodlar işyerinde kaldı yarın tekrardan yükleyip deniycem size ulaşırım. tekrar teşekkür ederim.

Comment: Hocam mesaj attım ama bu konuda yardımınıza ihtiyacım var.